# Prepare for segue delay. Information is lagging but being presented

Tags: swift, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm pushing otherUserUid and otherUserFullName to another view controller but it isn't being call immediately. The information is lagging behind and it takes 2 clicks for the information to appear.

I think preparForSegue: is being called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath: Any solutions how to fix this?

Cheers!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

```
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jsqDirectory", sender: self)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

    self.otherUserFullName = (currentCell.textLabel?.text)!
    print(self.otherUserFullName)

    self.otherUserUid = (currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text)!
    print(self.otherUserUid)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "jsqDirectory" {
        if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? JSQViewController{

            viewController.senderDisplayName = self.fullName
            viewController.senderId = self.firebase.authData.uid

            viewController.otherUid = self.otherUserUid
            viewController.otherUser = self.otherUserFullName
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("directoryCell") as UITableViewCell!
    let directoryItem = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = directoryItem.fullName
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = directoryItem.key
    cell.detailTextLabel!.hidden = true

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you have to perform segue at the end of Function like thiss..

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

self.otherUserFullName = (currentCell.textLabel?.text)!
print(self.otherUserFullName)

self.otherUserUid = (currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text)!
print(self.otherUserUid)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jsqDirectory", sender: self)
```

Comment: you were performing segue way too early than passing the values to next view Controller. make sure to Mark this answer as Correct and thumbs up